# Macro Code for remove duplicate cells from single column and repeat same for rest of the columns

Tags: vba, excel

I want to create macro for remove duplicate cells from single column and repeat same for rest of the columns.

I have code do this for single column and its working but I am not able to convert this code to repeat same process for rest of the columns.

Can anyone please help me with this?

[image: Columns]

```
Sub Delete_Dupes2()

Dim lastrow As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

With Sheet2

    lastrow = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    .Range("$A$1:$A$" & lastrow).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlYes
End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Here for the first 10 columns :

```
Sub Delete_Dupes3()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim LastRow As Long

With Sheet2
    For j = 1 To 10
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, j).End(xlUp).Row
        .Range(.Cells(1, j), .Cells(LastRow, j)).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, _
                                                                Header:=xlYes
    End If
End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

BTW, in you screenshot (probably dummy data), there is not headers and yet the argument says the opposite : `Header:=xlYes`

Answer (score 0):

Another way (R3uK posted while I was testing my answer).
I've added two ways of referencing the range - the first returns the row number, the second returns a reference to the cell.

As both R3uK and myself have put - rather than use `.Range("$A$1:$A$" & lastrow)` I find it easier to use `.Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(lastrow, 1))` as you refer to the column with a number rather than letter designation.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()

    Delete_Dupes2 1
    Delete_Dupes2 3
    Delete_Dupes2 ColumnNum:=5

    Dim x As Long
    For x = 1 To 10
        Delete_Dupes2 ColumnNum:=x
    Next x

End Sub


Sub Delete_Dupes2(ColumnNum As Long)

    Dim lastrow As Long
    Dim lastrow1 As Range

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    With Sheet2
            lastrow = .Cells(Rows.Count, ColumnNum).End(xlUp).Row
            .Range(.Cells(1, ColumnNum), .Cells(lastrow, ColumnNum)).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlYes
            'or
            'Set lastrow1 = .Cells(Rows.Count, ColumnNum).End(xlUp)
            '.Range(.Cells(1, ColumnNum), lastrow1).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlYes


    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

**Edit:**

Or you could change the procedure name to:
`Sub Delete_Dupes2(ColumnNum As Long, wrkSht As Worksheet)`

change the `With Sheet2` line to:
`With wrkSht`

change your calling (Test) lines to:

```
Delete_Dupes2 1, Sheet2
Delete_Dupes2 3, Sheet1
Delete_Dupes2 ColumnNum:=5, wrkSht:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("AnotherSheet")

Dim x As Long
For x = 1 To 10
    Delete_Dupes2 ColumnNum:=x, wrkSht:=ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("ASheetInAnotherFile")
Next x
```